# TypeLoadException on navigating to a page from usercontrol

Tags: vb.net, xaml, user-controls, windows-8.1

I have this code in my Usercontrol:

```
Private Sub tap(sender As Object, e As TappedRoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Tapped
     Try
        CType(Window.Current.Content, Frame).Navigate(GetType(calendar_day))
        'calendar_day is a page in project'
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.HelpLink)
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.HResult)
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException)
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Source)
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Output:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in Organize.exe

-2146233054

Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Foundation'.
mscorlib    
at System.StubHelpers.WinRTTypeNameConverter.GetTypeFromWinRTTypeName(String typeName, Boolean& isPrimitive)
at System.StubHelpers.SystemTypeMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(TypeNameNative* pNativeType, Type& managedType)
at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType)
at Organize.day_btn.clicked(Object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
```

I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, building for both x64 and x86, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I first created calendar_day as BlankPage1 and then renamed file and class. But in calendar_day.xaml I left `x:Class="Organize.BlankPage1"`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had a similar error and the reason was that Page class is supposed to live in Views namespace.